# SELECT(DISINCT) in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, ms-office, distinct

I couldn't find the solution to the problem I have in other *SELECT(DISINCT) in MS Access*-type questions and I've been struggling with it for a good few hours;

I've got a table *Photos* with two columns: *PhotoTypeId* and *PatientId*. Every patient can have multiple types of photos made multiple times.

Example:

```
PhotoTypeId,PatientId  
13,1050  
14,1050  
13,1050  
13,1051  
13,1054
```

Description:
Patient `#1050` had photos of type `13` and `14` taken, whereas patients `#1051` and `#1054` had only those of type `13`.

What I want to find is the type of photo that was made to the most distinct patients. In the example above, it's photo type `13`, cause it was made to 3 distinct patients (`#1050` twice, `#1051`, `#1054`)

I have to do it in MS Access and I want to do it using SQL. I tried something like:

```
SELECT PhotoId, COUNT(DISTINCT PatientId)
FROM Photos
GROUP BY PhotoId;
```

But MS Access doesn't support the COUNT(DISTINCT x) syntax; how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sub-query as MS access doesn't support that syntax :

```
select top 1 p.PhotoId, count(*)
from (select distinct PhotoId, PatientId from Photos
     ) as p
group by p.PhotoId
order by count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

MS Access does not support `count(disitnct)`.  But you can do:

```
select top 1 photoid, count(*)
from (select distinct photoid, patientid
      from photos
     ) as pp
group by photoid
order by count(*) desc;
```

MS Access treats `top 1` as `top 1 with ties`.  If you want only one row, then change the `order by`:

```
select top 1 photoid, count(*)
from (select distinct photoid, patientid
      from photos
     ) as pp
group by photoid
order by count(*) desc, photoid;
```